# How to download google-services.json file from firebase for Ionic?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-remote-config

I am developing an Ionic application with firebase. I have to fetch the remote config value from firebase. I don't have any idea how to download the google-services.json file. I cant find any tutorial for Ionic for fetching remote config value. If anybody has idea please help me.

Comment: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, i have followed that link, when i go to my settings it shows "There are currently no apps in the project Provider Application". I dont know how to add app and download google-services.json file.

Comment: "I dont know how to add app" - That's a different question and one you need to answer first. :-)

Comment: No sorry, i already tried that link but i cant find the download option, so it is relevant my question

Comment: Well to add aproject you go to your firebase console and click on the big plus sign wich is labeled "Add project". If you already have a project you have to select "Overview" in the top left corner of the console and then you click on another plus sign labled something like this: "Add app".

Comment: Thank you so much, i got it, i got the value. Thanks to everybody